# ¿Por qué tengo muchos errores en Unity 2022.2.5f1, cuando traté de crear un Apk?

Tags: unity

Saludos tengo muchos problemas para crear una apk en Unity. Estos son los siguientes errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otro error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otro error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Próximo error:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Último

Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 185 seconds (184683 ms)
3 errors
UnityEngine.GUIUtility: ProcessEvent (int, int ptr, bool&)

Comment: Hola JM, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y de paso evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Y de paso, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: El problema es de Unity, y he intentado resolver el problema y no he encontrado un solución al problema.